# Code to Check if a Cells is Empty and not on Weekend

Tags: excel, vba

I have a vba code to check if a value of column 2 is duplicate and then if duplicate is found go to check on the same row but different columns if a cells is empty check if it is on weekend(Dates are listed on the first row) and if it is not go back 3 cells and highlight the cell.

I have tried using a nested loop to check first if the value is duplicate then check if the cell is empty and different from weekend

```
lastRow = Range("B65000").End(xlUp).row
Sheet1.Activate
For i = 2 To lastRow 'loop to run the entire condition
If Trim(Cells(i, 2)) <> "" And Trim(Cells(i, 2)) <> "-" Then
If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("B2:B" & lastRow), Range   ("B" & i)) > 1 Then
For col = 5 To 17
If Trim(Cells(i, col)) = "" And Weekday(Cells(1, col)) <> 7 Or 1 Then
Cells(i, col - 3).Interior.Color = vbRed
End If
Next col
End If
End If
Next i
```

but it ends up highlighting the all the cells instead of just one cell

Comment: `If Weekday(Cells(1, col)) <> 7 Or Weekday(Cells(1, col)) <>1 Then`

Comment: When you say "Go back 3 cells" do you mean you want column 2 highlighted, or do you *actually* want to highlight 3 cells to the left of wherever it is blank?

Comment: Highlight 3 cells to the left of of wherever it is blank

Comment: @SJR i changed the code to what you suggested but still no difference

Comment: You need to think through your logic but you might need AND rather than OR.